# Graphing mutliple lines (999) on the same xy-plane in r

Tags: r

I have two variables that i want to bootstrap and graph the resulting linear regression line on the same xy plane from each new data set.

I was thinking that i can hold each resulting intercept and slope from the lm() but i dont know how i could graph that information for each resulting pair of information in the same graph. I know that abline() can do one pair  but not all of them. Feel free to throw anything at me.

```
intercept_stuff<-rep(NA,T)

opp_stuff<-rep(NA,T)
N<-1000
for(t in 1:T){
idx <- sample(1:N, size =N, replace=TRUE)
intercept_stuff[t]<- lm(oppose_any~local_topic ,data = facebook[idx, 
])$coefficient[1] 

opp_stuff[t]<- lm(oppose_any~local_topic ,data = facebook[idx, 
])$coefficient[2] 
}
```

Comment: Check out the `lines()` command.  Many other ideas [here](https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/olsresultplots.html).

Comment: Check out here for examples of bootstrapping plots.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/bootstrapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do multiple pairs of lines on `ggplot` with some simulated data. Hopefully this will give you some useful clues:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)

# simulate some data
obs <- c(1:90)
values1 <- rnorm(90,mean=0,sd=1)
values2 <- rnorm(90,mean=5,sd=2)
values3 <- rnorm(90,mean=10,sd=3)
df <- as.tibble(cbind(obs,values1,values2,values3))
```

It looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 90 x 4
     obs values1 values2 values3
   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    1.  -0.162    7.47   10.7 
 2    2.   0.518    5.17    7.61
 3    3.   1.52     7.66    4.42
# ... with 80 more rows
```

Then `melt` it into long form:

```
m.df <- melt(df,id="obs",measures=c("values1","values2","values3"))
```

to look like this:

```
> m.df
    obs variable       value
1     1  values1 -0.16228714
2     2  values1  0.51755370
3     3  values1  1.52433685
4     4  values1 -1.82067006
5     5  values1 -1.42180601
...
```

Then plot many lines (as long as there are groups like the `color` group here, they will be unique lines):

```
ggplot(m.df,aes(x=obs,y=value,color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

And here is the plot:

[image: stacked lines]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch this really helps